# how to create a hex file in keil?

Tags: microcontroller, 8051, keil

I want to programme at89s52 micro controller...using Keil u5. I searched on youtube googled it tried everything but cannot see the hex file. it says creating a hex file/location but there are no hex files in there they contain .c and .lnp files. please help me?

Answer (score 2):

First hit on google:

> QUESTION
>   Do the Keil Tools provide Intel HEX output for a device programmer?
>
> ANSWER FOR 8051, 251 AND 166 DEVICES
>   Open the project in the Keil IDE
>   Click the drop-down menu Project, then select Options for Target
>   Select the Output tab
>   Check Create HEX File
>   Select the proper HEX file format to create. Typically this will be HEX-80 for 8051 programs and HEX-386 for large C16x programs)
>   Click the OK button
>   Click the drop-down menu Project, then select Rebuild all target files - if the project builds without errors, the linker creates a hex file in the same location as the object files
>   The final part of the make process is converting the linker-created absolute object file into an Intel HEX-format file that should be compatible with any device programmer.
>
> If you do not build your projects with µVision, you need to run the Object HEX Converters (fore example OH51.EXE) after linking to convert the absolute object file produced by the linker into an Intel HEX file.

Comment: Maybe he meant "Bing"? :)